# Display webservice callout return data on a VF Page without saving data in records

Tags: apex, visualforce, webservices, callout

I'm kind of new on Salesforce. I've built an Apex class that makes a callout to a webservice and I want to display on a VFPage the data that the callout returns.

I've just been able to accomplish it by saving the data in records, so I save the data in an object record and then I display the record information. The callout is called when I click on a List button, and I would like to print the list view the data that the callout returns.

How can I do that without the needing of save the data in object records? I mean, if I save the callout return in a String variable, how can I refer to that variable from the VFPage?

Answer (score 4):

You actually have several choices here. A first, simplistic approach would be to store the data in a string variable and render it as part of the view state. This method certainly works, but it invokes a lot of view state being passed back and forth, plus overhead for the HTML rendering, and is still subject to other limits, like the View State limit of 135kb of data.

I'd recommend a @RemoteAction to simply call the service as a proxy, and then allow the client to render the values. That looks like this:

```
// Some JavaScript
function doCallback() {
  myController.doCallback(handleCallbackResult);
}
function handleCallbackResult(data, event) {
  // render the new data
}
```

And on the controller:

```
@RemoteAction global static String doCallback() {
    Http binding = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint(yourEndpoint);
    request.setMethod('GET'); // POST, etc.
    HttpResponse response = binding.send(request);
    return response.body();
}
```

You can also return complex types, like classes, and apply appropriate error handling, if your request can fail, and also supply parameters to the callout function, such as an ID for a record, some user-provided text, etc. Everything is transparently converted between JavaScript objects and Apex Code objects for you by the RemoteAction library.

You can even wire this whole thing up in your favorite JS library, like jQuery, AngularJS, etc, depending on your familiarity with those libraries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Finally, I tried to use a trigger with '@future' action in an Apex Class. Unfortunately, the '@future' action can't return any data but void, so is not useful for may case. Anyway, I'll keep in maind what you've suggested for display data in a page.

Comment: You can't callout directly from a trigger. It's a system limitation to prevent excessively long locks.

Comment: Thank you, this does seem to be a great approach to go. I'm a bit confused by the method of calling you're doing in the JavaScript. I'm familiar with the JavaScript Remoting calling pattern, but how does the JavaScript know about the this `doCallback()` function simply within the js script?

Comment: @qarthandso The Visualforce framework constructs a JavaScript proxy for your for all `@RemoteAction` methods in the page's controller and/or extensions. Assuming your class name was `myController`, the method would be generated as a function at `window.myController.doCallback`. The method must be global if the page is to be contained in an iframe, though, which is the only thing you need to watch out for. Do feel free to experiment with this, and you'll see how it works.

Comment: @sfdcfox this makes a lot of sense. And we put the callback function inside of the parenthesis `doCallback(hanleCallBackResult)` to tell it what callback function to use for the returned data?

Comment: @qarthandso Yes, the last parameter is the callback handler. See [RemoteAction Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_RemoteAction.htm) for more details.

Comment: @sfdcfox Awesome, thank you. I know this is not an appropriate place to ask this, but as a beginner being thrown into a large salesforce project, I can't help but wonder why it was chosen to write a proprietary language, APEX, instead of extend an existing similar language to handle all of this logic. Is this just a business decision to make it more specialized or was there really a technical need for a new language?

Comment: @qarthandso It'd probably be better off as a full question by itself, because it's an interesting topic, but in summary, it was modeled after Java, so as to be "portable" to those familiar with Object-Oriented Programming (and because the platform itself is in Java), but it solves specific problems with multi-tenancy and interfacing with the database, such as providing inline queries, interfacing with the standard sharing model, and other platform-specific challenges that Java was not well-equipped to handle safely and securely.

Comment: Made it a new [question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148414/new-to-salesforce-and-wondering-why-apex-was-created). thank you though. Really appreciate all the info.

Comment: @sfdcfox [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.204.0.pages.meta/pages/pages_js_remoting_invoking.htm) seems to describe the method you were mentioning a comments ago about calling a method. The next page after jumps right to using the `{!$RemoteAction.controller.method}` syntax. Is there certain documentation that describes how you learned that VF constructs a JS proxy for all remoteaction methods? I seem to be missing a conceptual part to all of this and am just trying to fill in the holes. Also for parameters, can I use a js array? is that what it means using commas?

Comment: @qarthandso The part about "proxies" isn't explicitly mentioned in the documentation (that I'm aware of), but various error messages you can encounter will mention them. For parameters, they must not be in an array, but set as one parameter per method parameter, for example, if the Apex method has 2 parameters, the JS code must provide three parameters, one for each method and the callback. You can call those proxies directly, or by using $RemoteAction, whichever you prefer. I usually call them direct in personal projects, but $RemoteAction in code I intend to package/distribute.